# Can I use a Reserved Instance or Savings Plan for Neptune?

Tags: amazon-neptune, amazon-savings-plans

Is it possible to apply a Reserved Instance or Savings Plan towards the instances I am using for Neptune? For example, I currently have a Neptune cluster with a single db.r4.large instance. Would purchasing a Compute Savings Plan discount my Neptune instance accordingly?

From the savings plan [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/savingsplans/pricing/):

> These plans automatically apply to EC2 instance usage regardless of instance family, size, AZ, region, OS or tenancy...

I understand that Neptune isn't EC2. It does use an instance though so I'm wondering if it would work. I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today, Neptune is not part of the Compute Savings Plan, but we are interested in options that give customers a discount for usage commitments.

Thanks, --Brad